# Robot framework - Ride - unable to OpenBrowser - nothing specific in the log

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I'm trying to run this simple test on RIDE, but I cannot figure out it's failing without giving me any specific details:

Ride Log

```
command: pybot.bat --argumentfile c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\RIDEe2en9t.d\argfile.txt --listener C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotide\contrib\testrunner\TestRunnerAgent.py:49555:False C:\Python27\Scripts\test\Login\login_suite.robot

========================================================================================================================================================================
Login Suite   

========================================================================================================================================================================

login_user                                                                                                                                                      | FAIL |
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/displayhelpservlet.css" media="all"/>
  <link href="/assets/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
  <script src="/assets/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/displayhelpservlet.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var json = Object.freeze('{"consoleLink":"/wd/hub","type":"Standalone","version":"3.11.0","class":"org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DisplayHelpServlet$DisplayHelpServletConfig"}');
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="content">
  <div id="help-heading">
    <h1><span id="logo"></span></h1>
    [ Message content over the limit has been removed. ]
      </span>
    </p>
    <p>
      Happy Testing!
    </p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <footer id="help-footer">
      Selenium is made possible through the efforts of our open source community, contributions from
      these <a href="https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/AUTHORS">people</a>, and our
      <a href="http://www.seleniumhq.org/sponsors/">sponsors</a>.
   </footer>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Selenium server is started (standalone-3.11.0) 
Python version 2.7 
Environment Path is set Python27/Scripts

Here is the test code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
login_user
    SeleniumLibrary.Open Browser    Google.com    googlechrome
    Maximize Browser Window
    Title Should Be    Google
```

The webdriver for Chrome is also set in Scripts folder, but I've tried it with Firefox as well and got the same result.

Comment: Have you verified that Chrome Driver is in the (Windows) path? This can be done by running `chromedriver` from the command line. In addition have you installed the SeleniumLibrary? (Hint, did you run `pip install SeleniumLibrary`? ). There is no need for the Jar file in a simple example. This is the role of the Python SeleniumLibrary.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:

so i have tried with this code

```
 *** Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
login_user
    SeleniumLibrary.Open Browser    https://google.com    googlechrome
    Maximize Browser Window
    Title Should Be    Google
```

If you have

- Selenium
- Robot Framework
- RIDE     (for running robot files)
- Chrome

The only thing you have  to do is download chromedriver.
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.38/

After you have download the chromedriver put it to a folder and add it to your path.

The way i have done after unzipping chromedriver

Ubuntu:

```
 sudo mv chromedriver /usr/local/bin/
 sudo chown root:root /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

Windows:

- put chromedriver.exe into a folder in this example  C:\drivers\
- Press Windows button on your keyboard and type Edit the system environment variables
- Under Advanced tab, Click Environment Variables
- List item
- Under System Variables find "Path" and click on Path and Edit button
- Click new and add the path where you have put the chromedriver

in this example   C:\drivers\chromedriver

Comment: I just started RF with this tutorial that is using RIDE as a example for making test syntax. And it does not matter if i use [SeleniumLibrary.Open Browser    Google.com    ff ] or
[Open Browser    Google.com    ff]
also ff is for fire fox and by the tutorial it says that is included in RF, unlike Chrome driver that i need to download. The result is the same. 

Beside the Selenium web server, should i install something else ?

Comment: RF does NOT include drivers, it's a framework. Just try it the way i showed you, the way you were trying is not useful in long term since the point of the framework is reusable keywords.

Comment: There is no point in using Python for a simple example like opening the Google home page. This is supported by the SeleniumLibrary. This library is an external library and requires to be installed seperately.

Comment: @A.Kootstra just like i said in the last line of my answer. Next time read it before you comment.

Comment: I read your answer and that particular line, and my comment was written with that in mind. Please do not make assumptions with respect to what someone did or did not do. I still think that this answer does not help someone at this experience level. Especially when a much simpler approach is available.

Comment: but you have just repeated what i have wrote, updated my answer hope it helps now :)